# "Z-value" equivalent for sample variance

Tags: variance, sample, unbiased-estimator, bounds

For a random variable $X$ (mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$, kurtosis $\kappa$), I take $n$ i.i.d. samples $X_1,\dots,X_n$ and find their mean, $\hat \mu^{(n)}$. By linearity of expectation, I know it has mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. But the Central Limit Theorem tells me more: that the mean is approximately distributed by $N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$ for large $n$.

The sample variance is $s^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\Sigma_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu^{(n)})$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance) (citing [this source](https://ijpam.eu/contents/2005-21-3/10/10.pdf) that I can't follow) says that it has expectation $\sigma^2$ (this being the point of Bessel's correction) and variance $\frac{\sigma^4}{n}(\kappa-1+\frac{2}{n-1})$.

Is there a corresponding limit theorem that says I can approximate $s^2$ by a normal distribution for large $n$? If not, what is my best method of approximating the probability that $|s^2-\sigma^2|$ would be larger than an arbitrary value $k$ - can I use Chernoff bounds somehow?

Comment: A generalization of the CLT indeed applies--but this is not a good approach.  Ordinarily you should look at $s^2/\sigma^2$ and use a chi-squared distribution to evaluate it.  It's difficult to provide advice, though, because you haven't provided a statistical context to help us understand what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.

Comment: @whuber I've got two distributions $Y,Z$ and pick one at random (w.p. 1/2 each). From a sample of the chosen distribution's _sample variance_ specifically, I want a percentage chance that the distribution was $Y$. I'm looking at some concrete cases of $Y,Z$ (Bernoulli, Geometric etc.) but want as general an approach as possible.

Comment: Then you definitely want to base your evaluation on the ratio.  In many cases it will approximately have an F distribution and the nature of the exceptions is extremely well studied.